# Ansible, ec2_remote_facts. Using vars in the roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

Please give advice. How to use vars from ec2_remote_facts in the roles?

```
---

- name: Sandbox
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Get facts by filter
     ec2_remote_facts:
       region: "{{ aws_default_region }}"
       filters:
         instance-state-name: running
         "tag:Group": "{{ aws_default_instance_tag_group }}"
     register: ec2_remote_facts

   - name: Add running sandbox instances to in-memory inventory host group
     add_host:
       hostname: "{{ item.public_ip_address }}"
       groups: running
     with_items: "{{ ec2_remote_facts.instances }}"

- name: prov
  hosts: running
  gather_facts: true
  user: ec2-user
  become: true
  roles:
    - httpd
```

In this case I would like to use some of the vars from running instances for httpd role.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 3 ways:

#### Define variable within `add_host` task:

```
- name: Add running sandbox instances to in-memory inventory host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.public_ip_address }}"
    groups: running
    ec2_interfaces: "{{ item.interfaces }}"
  with_items: "{{ ec2_remote_facts.instances }}"
```

#### Call `ec2_facts` as pre-task:

```
- name: prov
  hosts: running
  gather_facts: true
  user: ec2-user
  become: true
  pre_tasks:
    - ec2_facts:
  roles:
    - httpd
```

#### Use `hostvars`:

```
- name: prov
  hosts: running
  gather_facts: true
  user: ec2-user
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: httpd
      first_instance_interfaces: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ec2_remote_facts.instances[0].interfaces }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great solution